# copy database table value from one to another based on Id search in SQL

Tags: sql

Lets make this shorter. I have three tables named Invoice_Info, Invoice_print, Product_sold. Table definitions are given below

Invoice_Info:

```
[InvoiceNo]
[InvoiceDate]
[SubTotal]
[VATPer]
[DiscountPer]
[GrandTotal]
[TotalPayment]
```

Invoice_print:

```
[InvoiceNo]
[InvoiceDate]
[SubTotal]
[VATPer]
[DiscountPer]
[GrandTotal]
[TotalPayment]
```

ProductSold:

```
[Id]
[InvoiceNo]
[ProductID]
[ProductName]
[Price]
```

Now I need to copy the data existed in invoice_info to invoice_print based on productSold's invoiceNo matching.
before every time i copy i need to delete all values exists in Invoice_print.
so I wrote the query to delete from invoice_print:

```
Delete from Invoice_print
```

Then to copy values from invoice_info to invoice_print I wrote :

```
INSERT INTO Invoice_print (InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, SubTotal, VATPer, DiscountPer, GrandTotal, TotalPayment)
SELECT InvoiceNo,
    InvoiceDate,
    Subtotal,
    VATPer,
    DiscountPer,
    GrandTotal,
    TotalPayment
FROM Invoice_Info.ProductSold
WHERE Invoice_info.InvoiceNo = ProductSold.InvoiceNo
    AND Invoice_Info.invoiceNo = txtInvoiceno.TEXT
```

Here I have took a value from a textbox named txtInvoiceno.
This query giving me error

> Ambiguous column name "InvoiceNo"

How to solve this problem ? 
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Was there supposed to be a JOIN in your SELECT?  It looks like you're trying to use the deprecated ANSI-89 style comma joins and used a period instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
SELECT InvoiceNo
```

with

```
SELECT ProductSold.InvoiceNo
```

and it will start working